How to test whether a nonparametric function is equal to 0?
There is an unknown function $h(x)=E(Y|X=x)$ which I estimated with a nonparametric series estimator (also called sieve estimator) $\widehat{h}(x)$ using data $\{Y_i,X_i\}_{i=1}^n$. I'm interested in testing $H_0: h(x)=0 (\text{for any}\ x)$ versus $H_1: h(x)\neq 0$(with strictly positive probability). How should I do the test?

Are you prepared to make further assumptions, in particular something like that the distribution of $Y-h(X)$ is independent of $X$ and that $Y_i-h(X_i)$ are i.i.d.?

@ChristianHennig Thanks Christian! I think I'm ok with assuming data are i.i.d., which implies $Y_i-h(X_i)$ are i.i.d.. But I will not assume $Y-h(X)$ is independent of $X$ (they are uncorrelated, and assuming independence would mean I need joint normality which I don't want to assume).

Sorry, but if you say $Y_i-h(X_i)$ are i.i.d., this implies that $Y-h(X)$ is independent of $X$, as otherwise  $Y_i-h(X_i)$ could not be identically distributed. It does not imply normality though, I was asking about any distribution. Under these assumptions it would be possible to construct something of a permutation test, I think. I'll later make this an answer unless you get something better in the meantime.

@ChristianHennig Hi Chris, good point! What I meant was that ${Y_i,X_i}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. (across $i$), this is compatible with $Y-h(X)$ being statistically dependent on $X$. For example, we could have $E((Y-h(X))^2|X)=X^2$, usually known as conditional heteroskedasticity in the regression literature.  I want to allow the distribution of $Y−h(X)$ to depend on $X$. That's to say, even under $H_0$, $Y-h(X)=Y$ could depend on $X$ via higher order moments.

I suspect there may be something in the literature, but I'm too lazy to search it for you.
What you can do in any case is a permutation test. Assume that $Y_i-h(X_i)$ are i.i.d. and in particular they don't depend on $X_i$ (in other words, $Y_i$ depends on $X_i$ only through $h$). This means that under the null hypothesis the $Y_i$ are i.i.d. with $E(Y_i)=0$. Your test statistic can be $T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\hat h(X_i))^2$ (you may also use $|Y_i-\hat h(X_i)|$). The distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis can be simulated by generating many data sets permuting the $Y_i$, and you can reject the null hypothesis at level $\alpha$ if $T$ as obtained from your real data is smaller than the $\alpha$-quantile of the distribution of $T$ as obtained from the permuted data sets ($\hat h$ needs to be re-fitted for each data set).
This is because if the null hypothesis is true, $T$ should not be much lower than $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i^2$, because $\hat h(X_i)$ is not in fact informative about $Y_i$ and $\hat h$ should optimally be zero, whereas if the null hypothesis is false, $\hat h$ should give a much better fit of the $Y_i$ than the constant 0. Permuting the $Y_i$ means removing any dependence between $Y_i$ and $X_i$, which I assume is only through $h$.
This may still give you a rough indication if in fact under $H_0: E(Y_i)=0$ but the distribution of $Y_i$ may depend on $X_i$ in other ways, but chances are it is not in general theoretically valid in that case anymore. Of course you can look at the data and see whether the result looks credible anyway.
I don't have a reference but I suspect you can find an example like this in general treatments of permutation tests.

Thanks, Christian! This is very helpful and has many good intuitions! Can you add some reference for the tests you mentioned, especially references that provide the asymptotic distribution of the test statistics under the null?

@ExcitedSnail Sorry, as I said I don't have the time to look for references. Also note that the principle of permutation tests is particularly useful because you do not need the asymptotic distribution of the test statistic; the permutation principle simulates it for you.

@ExcitedSnail Keep in mind you are asking for free help on the internet. If this were a collaborative project that would offer me co-authorship, I'd be up for doing something more (in that case you can contact me via email; I'm easy to find).

Thanks a lot, Christian! This is very helpful. Will contact you in the future for joint project.
